# Redewendung wenn man an ein fremdes Telefon gehen muss

Tags: word-choice, telephone-conversation

Im Arbeitsumfeld gibt es üblicherweise mehr oder minder festgelegte Formulierungen, die man benutzt; etwas in der Art von *Firma Meier, Michael Müller, Apparat von Peter Schmitz* hört man öfter.

Im privaten Umfeld fühle ich mich aber immer unwohl dabei, an ein fremdes Telefon zu gehen. Wenn ich irgendwo zu Gast bin und der Gastgeber gerade im Keller ist oder mit beiden Händen im Kuchenteig steckt und ruft "Gehen Sie mal eben ran?", was sagt man dann, wenn man abhebt? Verwendet man evtl. verschiedene Formulierungen, je nachdem wie gut man den Gastgeber kennt?

Comment: Bei der Arbeit gibt es auch "Müller **für** Maier"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ich weiß nicht, ob es noch aktuell ist, da wegen der Mobilfunkverbreitung private Festnetztelefone immer seltener angerufen werden, aber früher habe ich das so gehandhabt:

```
bei + Nachname
```

also zum Beispiel

> bei Schmidt

Eventuell kann man auch noch den eigenen Namen erwähnen, wenn es sehr formell sein muss:

> Bei Schmidt – Sie sprechen mit Thomas Mustermann.

Comment: +1, *Bei* kenne ich auch so.

Comment: +1 Ja, ich auch :)

Comment: Dito. Und für den Fall, dass man bei jemand anderem ist und einen Anruf erwartet "Schmidt, bei Mustermann".

Comment: "Bei" ist Standard, aber erfahrungsgemäß wird es oft überhört - wenn man sich angewöhnt, immer den eigenen Namen dazuzusagen, kann man sich viel Verwirrung sparen. ("Ich hab bei Schmidt gesagt! Stop, ich bin nicht Schmidt!")

Comment: Auch gängig ist das Gleiche, nur noch umgedreht: "Müller bei Wurstalarm" wenn Herr/Frau Müller ans Telefon von den Wurstalarms geht.

Comment: @Cass: Um das Überhören zu verhindern gibt es auch noch die Variante "Hier bei Müller"