# How do I answer a phone call?

Tags: telephone-conversation

When somebody calls me on the phone I need to say something when answering. In English (similar to other languages) it may be sufficient to just say

> *"Hello"*

Is it accepted to just say *"Hallo"* when answering a phone call? Are there any conventions on what to say in a private setting, or in my company?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are indeed many people just saying "Hallo?" or "Ja?".
But also very common with most pople answering a private (landline) number and not knowing the caller, is saying their last name.
If it's a business phone, then of course you say the name of the company, your full name and a greeting.

Answer (score 15):

I think it depends if you're answering a personal cell phone or a landline phone which is used by more than one person.

When I answer my cell phone and I the caller ID is shown on the display, I answer according to my relationship to the caller. For example:

> *(friend)*
>   Hallo, Anna! *(or simply)* Hallo!
>
> *(business related)*
>   Guten Tag! *(or very friendly)* Guten Tag Frau Schmidt!

If I don't know who is calling (unknown number, of suppressed caller ID etc.), I normally pronounce the *hallo* as question:

> Hallo?
>   *or*
>   Peter Meyer. Hallo?

---

Related question:
[Redewendung wenn man an ein fremdes Telefon gehen muss](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/redewendung-wenn-man-an-ein-fremdes-telefon-gehen-muss)

Answer (score 5):

It is getting more and more accepted to simply say "Hallo" when answering the phone. Personally, I don't like this kind of greeting. Voices on the phone often sound quite different than they do in real life. I often don't recognize the person on the other end and have to ask something like "Bill, is that you?"

So, I'd suggest that on a private number you simply respond to the call by saying your name ("Hans Mustermann" or simply "Mustermann"). On a cororate line I'd answer something like ("Firma XYZ, Mustermann, guten Tag!").

Answer (score 4):

IMO saying at least your last name when answering your phone is a matter of politeness: humans voices tend to sound unfamiliar over the phone, so the caller can easily know if he got the right person without the awkward question "X, is that you?".

I talked to people, which rather not say their name when answering their private phone due to privacy concern, but I don't really get their point there: I'm sure that if I wanted to get their name basic social engineering tricks would do the job.

Comment: I used to do that too. However I don't think you have to be particularly polite when answering a phone anymore. Someone else wants something from *me* (the least of which is my time). It also creates a lot of confusion when e.g. you still live with your parents and get confused with your father/mother all the time. All this only applies when I don't know/see the caller ID.

Answer (score 2):

I answer the phone by simply saying "Ja?", or my surname and nothing else. The caller greets the callee with a "Hallo", however I see more and more people change that to either localized greetings or general greetings, like "morgen", "guten tag", "guten abend", etc. It seems quite weird to answer Skype calls with a Hallo, for some reason.

For some reason, the localized greetings are also accepted in many places (such as the German military, the Bundeswehr).

It is alright to say "<surname>, moin". When I called customer support in southern areas in Germany, I was greeted with a "grüß Gott", quite often.

Answer (score 2):

These examples are taken from this [pdf](http://www.wirtschaftsdeutsch.de/lehrmaterialien/redemittel-telefon-allgemein.pdf) (**It will download a pdf file**)

There are lots of possibilty to accept a call. The person, who is accepting the call, should decide which one to choose. The examples below are mostly for the business world.

> Breitenbach KG, Einkauf, Gottfried Schmitt am Apparat. (Was kann ich
> für Sie tun?)
>
> Breitenbach AG, Zentrale. Guten Tag.
>
> Vornweg&Co, Helmut Fischer. Grüß Gott.
>
> Guten Tag, hier ist Firma Maibach & Söhne, Papierverarbeitung, mein Name ist Edwin Huber.
>
> Vorzimmer des Vorstandsvorsitzenden Dr. Herzfeld, Britta Droste.
>
> Schmitt, Apparat Stalke.
>
> Apparat von Herrn Stalke.
>
> Neumannn GmbH, Kleinert am Apparat,
>
> Huber.
>
> Eva Kleinert.

Comment: Some organisations, specifically in public administration, have real bandworms of required phone prases. Employees are instructed to follow these 100%, so it may well be the first 30 seconds of your call are used up by this. *"Landesbehörden Baden-Württemberg, Staatliche Fachstelle für das öffentliche Forstwesen im Regierungsbezirk Freiburg, Sie sprechen mit Hans-Dietrich Sommer-Fröhlich, Guten Tag!"* would not be uncommon...

Comment: @tofro You are right. Because of the fact that the introduction part mostly lasts too long and I cannot find a suitable answer to this question: who call me? :)

Comment: +1, that PDF looks like an excellent and comprehensive resource.