# Welche Telefonbegrüßungen gibt es?

Tags: telephone-conversation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I answer a phone call?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-answer-a-phone-call)

Ich frage mich regelmäßig, welche Begrüßungen am Telefon üblich sind und welche wann angebracht sind. Sowohl beim Anrufen als auch beim Angerufenwerden.

Ich persönlich sage

- "*nachname*, mein Name" wenn ich anrufe und den Angerufenen nicht kenne
- "*vorname* *nachname*" wenn ich angerufen werde
- "Hallo" oder "Hallo *vorname vom Anrufer*" wenn ich sicher weiß, um wen es geht

"*nachname*, mein Name" klingt aber vielleicht ein bisschen altbacken...

Daher die Gretchenfrage:
Wie haltet ihr's mit dem Begrüßen?

Comment: "Chilenischer Katzenfriedhof, Müller am Apparat."

Comment: Related: [Redewendung wenn man an ein fremdes Telefon gehen muss](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2656/1224)